# What is the Q equivalent for Bluebird's .spread?

Tags: node.js, bluebird, q

In Bluebird, when a promise resolves and we resolve it with an array of values - there's an option to use .spread function to separate values back from the array and pass them as arguments for the next .then, like so:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

var val1 = 1;
var val2 = 2;

//Since resolve takes only 1 arg - we join these into array
resolve([val1, val2]);

})
.spread(function(val1, val2){
    //val1 and val2 are separate again
});
```

**How do I do this with Q?**

It seems to also have a .spread function but it's purpose is to be applied on an array of Promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spread()`. Just as in bluebird.